# How to make mesh move as one

Tags: mesh

I'm rigging a model to a new rig, and every time I parent it to the new rig the mesh of the model is fine.
That is until I move it and everything moves except the eyes which move in their own directions. I've been trying to solve this for a while now and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Solved! I just forgot to apply the modifier.